# set div height using jquery (stretch div height)

Tags: jquery, css

I have 3 divs with ids `header`, `content` and `footer`. Header and footer has fixed height and they are styled to float on top and bottom. I want the middle `content` height calculated automatically with jquery. How can I make this possible??

```
#header {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#footer {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: By default, don't browsers automatically calculate height to the content of a div?

Comment: The header and footer have `position:fixed`?

Comment: @Šime, probably to fit between header and footer..

Comment: automatic div height=100% wont work in firefox.. I kan fix this if i get the height in px and then i can subtract header and footer heights, and setting the top margin will float my div between header and footer `:)`

Comment: @basteralfred trying adding `height: 100%` to the html and body tags. Then it should

Answer (score 68, accepted):

well you can do this:

```
$(function(){

    var $header = $('#header');
    var $footer = $('#footer');
    var $content = $('#content');
    var $window = $(window).on('resize', function(){
       var height = $(this).height() - $header.height() + $footer.height();
       $content.height(height);
    }).trigger('resize'); //on page load

});
```

see fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/JVKbR/  
demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/JVKbR/show/

Comment: now it works!! its something bug with my jquery file.. thanks :)

Comment: @blasteralfred newer versions of FF does not allow window manipulation unless the user specifically allows it in their preferences.

Comment: hi @RobertMullaney , thanks for the update ... but as Neal said, "none of this is window manipulation" +1 .. :)

Comment: My apologies, I must have added that comment while looking at a similar issue that was attempting a scripted size adjustment.

PS: True, while it's not modifying the window attributes, though technically we are manipulating the window object by adding a listener... semantics :P

Comment: You forgot to put brackets around `$('#header').height() + $('#footer').height()` though. The calculation of `var height` is not correct now.

Comment: Why aren't you also caching `#content`?

Comment: Haha I did not notice that @Shmiddty ... Now I am ^_^

Comment: @Jules There is no order of operations for addition and subtraction. You will get the same thing no matter what order it is in...

Comment: When resizing, you should debounce the the callback so that you are not resizing the table for every resize event.  As you drag the browser window you are pummeled with resize events.  Debounce will only let you receive the event for a duration after they have stopped coming in.  You will notice a remarkable improvement in the performance of your page.

Answer (score 16):

The correct way to do this is with good-old CSS:

```
#content{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:35px;
    bottom:35px;
}
```

And the bonus is that you don't need to attach to the window.onresize event! Everything will adjust as the document reflows. All for the low-low price of four lines of CSS!

Comment: That's a nice alternative approach. I like Zirak's answer best because it's what OP asked for (jQuery answer).

Answer (score 15):

Off the top of my head:

```
$('#content').height(
    $(window).height() - $('#header').height() - $('#footer').height()
);
```

Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 5):

You can bind function as follows, instead of init on load

```
$("div").css("height", $(window).height());
$(​window​).bind("resize",function() {
    $("div").css("height", $(window).height());
});​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ contsize();});
$(window).bind("resize",function(){contsize();});

function contsize()
{
var h = window.innerHeight;
var calculatecontsize = h - 70;/*if header and footer heights= 35 then total 70px*/ 
$('#content').css({"height":calculatecontsize + "px"} );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think will work.

```
$('#DivID').height('675px');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
    document.querySelector('#middle').style.height = 
    window.innerHeight - $('#header').height() + $('#footer').height() + 'px';
}, true);
```