# Make a div vertically responsive - bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like the `<div>` to adjust its height a/g to the browser's height. Is this possible?
If the browser's height is decreased, (say to simulate a view in tablet/phone), the login button is not visible.

[See my code example here](http://www.bootply.com/AzARCetkTu)

So as not to show scrollbars, I used

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: check out min-height and max-height

Comment: Did not work. Is it because of overflow prop. I set.

Comment: This one worked

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541115/set-div-height-using-jquery-stretch-div-height

Answer (score 2):

You can use Viewport-percentage lengths combined with the `min-height` and `min-width` properties. VW is the viewport-width and VH is the viewport height. Thus, `min-height: 100vh`is the complete height of the viewport. [The documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) will give you more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript, whenever you resize the page you change your div height. This solution will work in any browser without any problem.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('#your_div_id').height($('body').height());
});
```

Comment: rupe fashu raspunsul asta!