# HTML - Make Div expand or contract based on size

Tags: html, css

I want a div to expand dynamically, so that the content under it is always visible. I have the following html:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="expandableDiv container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                @Html.Partial("_company")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="companyNavBar">
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="#section-documents">Documents</a>
            <a href="#section-holdings">Holdings</a>
            <a href="#section-transactions">Transactions</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    @{Html.RenderAction("Documents", "Company");}
    @{Html.RenderAction("Holdings", "Company");}
    @{Html.RenderAction("Transactions", "Company");}
</div>
```

Based on some data, the height of the div with the html partial will vary. Currently the div with class=companyNavBar is hidden if the original height grows. How do I make it always visible?

This is my css:

```
.content {
position: absolute;
top: 310px;
left: 19px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
overflow-y: scroll;
background-color: white;
}

.companyNavBar {
    margin-left: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery, you can use determine the viewports height by using the following (change windows to specific div if needed)

```
var height = $(window).height()
```

you can do something similar with your div and determine how large it should be. You can then set the height of your div accordingly:

```
$('#divName').height(<new height>)
```

Please see the following stack overflow which is nearly the same question for additional code and help:

[set div height using jquery (stretch div height)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541115/set-div-height-using-jquery-stretch-div-height)