# Calculate height of 3 elements and find the biggest

Tags: jquery

good Day

I want to calculate the outerheight of 3 elements and return the biggest one, since their sizes can vary at any given time...

Here is what I have:

```
var a = $('#latestInner').outerHeight();
var b = $('#make').outerHeight();
var c = $('#models').outerHeight();

if (a > b, c) {
    a = x;
}
else if (b > a, c) {
    b = x;
}
else if (c > a, b) {
    c = x;
}
```

How would I proceed? I know I can probably use an array but not sure how to..

Comment: The expression in `(a > b, c)` uses the JavaScript comma operator which returns the right-most expression's result, in this case `c` so `(a > b, c)` is the same as `(a > c)`.

Comment: I see, thank you. just wanted to make an effort

Comment: This is similar to other questions asked here about [equalizing heights of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275850/set-a-div-height-equal-with-of-another-div/3276032) although the code here is more compact :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate max using each method:

```
var max = 0;
$('#latestInner, #make, #models').each(function() {
    max = Math.max(max, $(this).outerHeight());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uwsJH/

If you need to update the height of the divs to be the same you can set it right away:

```
var max = 0;
$('#latestInner, #make, #models').each(function() {
    max = Math.max(max, $(this).outerHeight());
})
.height(max);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uwsJH/1/

Comment: Well, I don't think it's going to be too heavy for just 3 divs. Anyway OP calculates `outerHeight` for each div. I just added `each` loop.

Answer (score 5):

Use  [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

> Returns the largest of zero or more numbers.

```
Math.max([value1[,value2[, ...]]])
```

Using jquery you can do:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null, $.map($('#latestInner, #make, #models'), function(n){ 
    return $(n).outerHeight(); 
}));
```

Comment: thank you, but how do you actually return the max value as say a variable z?

Comment: tank you for your answer CD..., appreciate