# Auto Adjust Div Height

Tags: html, height, match

I want the div that's on the right side to match the height of the div that's on the left. The div on the right should always be the same height as the div on the left. The div on the left auto adjust its height. Both divs should always have the same height. A picture is worth a thousand words so please take a look at the picture below.

**Here's the image that explains my problem.**

http://i44.tinypic.com/24pcpwj.jpg

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/zFqNH/

**HTML**

```
 <div style="width:1053px;">
 <section id="inside" style="overflow: hidden; width:310px; float:right; border-left:0;"> 
 <ul>
 <p class="title">Funny</p>

<li class="list">
    <img src="http://cdn.dashburst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat.jpg"      width="100" height="67" style="float:left;padding-right:15px;" /></a>
    <h3 style="font-size:20px;">Grumpy Cat</h3>        
</li>
 </ul>
 </section>

 <section id="inside">   
 <h2 class="subheading">Grumpy Cat<br/><p style="font-size:14px; margin-top:0px; font-weight:normal;"></p></h2><h2 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; padding-top:10px;"></h2>                                    
 <p class="section"></p>                              

 <img src="http://cdn.dashburst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat.jpg" border="0" style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;" height="396" width="700">
 <br/>                                      
     <img src="http://cdn.dashburst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat.jpg" border="0" style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;" height="396" width="700">
 <br/>
         <img src="http://cdn.dashburst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat.jpg" border="0" style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;" height="396" width="700">
 <br/>

 </div></div></section>
```

**CSS**

```
  #inside { 
width:700px; 
border-right: 1px solid #dddddd; 
border-left: 1px solid #dddddd; 
min-height: 600px; 
overflow: hidden; 
padding-bottom:15px;    
  }
  .title{
width:300px;
padding-top:3px;
padding-bottom:7px;
color:#fff;
height:20px;    
margin-top:125px; 
background:#2c2c2c;         
font-size: 18px;
  }
  .section{
padding-left:30px; 
padding-bottom:15px; 
margin-bottom: 1px; 
font-size: 28px;
color: #657B83;
  }
  .subheading {
background:#fff;    
font-size:50px;         
height:100px;
position: relative; 
  }

  .bottom {
border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;    
border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;    
padding-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 10px;   
width:1053px;       
position:relative;
margin: 0 auto; 
font-size:15px;
color: #fff;    
  }
  .list{
width:300px; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
padding-bottom:10px; 
display: inline-block; 
margin-top:20px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert JavaScript below the two divs and use document.getElementById to get the height of the left div, then use document.getElementById to change the height of the right div.

```
<script>
  var height = document.getElementById('div1').style.height;
  document.getElementById('div2').style.height = height;
</script>
```

**Documentation:**
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_height.asp

Comment: It doesn't quite work. I tried it and it messed everything up. Is there a solution to just using CSS?

Comment: There's no way to do this with just CSS, you need to use JavaScript or jQuery.  Your div id's need to be unique from each other.  Please take a look at the jQuery answers given for this similiar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275850/set-a-div-height-equal-with-of-another-div

Comment: Can you please tell me how this website does it? The sidebar on this website stretches all the way down. http://www.theverge.com/2013/11/1/5053878/android-4-4-kitkat-and-google-quest-for-the-next-billion

Comment: They do it with something like this http://jsfiddle.net/keenydev/ufpzQ/6/.
Nest the two divs (left div and right div) in another div (main div) and set the left/right div's height to 100%.  Float left on both divs and put a border-right on the left div

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I will accept your answer just because you helped me all the along